# AngularJS request JSON from other domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, cors

I'm trying to retrieve data from the Wikia API with the following code. But everything seems to fail. As far as I understand CORS has to be enabled on the server, from which I am trying to retrieve data. However I don't know if that's the case with Wikia. So JSONP seems to be the only way. But im getting the error

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://adventuretime.wikia.com/api/v1/Articles/List?expand=1&category=Episodes&limit=200. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://website.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I've read the AngularJS docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

And numerous questions on stackoverflow. Is there anything terrible wrong with my code? Angular should support CORS and JSONP requests natively

My code is following:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="episodes">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Episodes</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="workshop.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController as app">

    <table>
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Url</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="episode in app.episodes">
                <td>{{episode.title}}</td>
                <td>{{episode.url}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**workshop.js**

```
(function(){
    angular
        .module('episodes', [])
        .controller('AppController', function($http){
            var app = this;

            app.episodes = $http({
                url: "http://adventuretime.wikia.com/api/v1/Articles/List?expand=1&category=Episodes&limit=200",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });

        });
})();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance for any help

**EDIT**

The Response Headers are:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Cacheable: YES
Age: 0
X-Cache: ORIGIN, MISS, MISS
Content-Length: 21965
X-Served-By: ap-s21, cache-wk-sjc3160-WIKIA, cache-fra1233-FRA
X-Backend-Response-Time: 2.267
Server: Apache
X-Timer: S1439118796.704444,VS0,VE2447
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Cache-Hits: ORIGIN, 0, 0
```

Comment: JSONP would also have to be supported by the server.  (The returned JS snippet needs to call your callback.)

Comment: @Noah Could you explain the callback? It seems that the server support JSONP but I'm getting a MIME error now

Comment: The Wikipedia article on the subject explains: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 0):

Try use `$http.jsonp(url);` for cross domain requests;

[Angularjs api - $http.jsonp();](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)

Comment: Wow - it seems to work and let me request the data!
I would have though that the shorthand jsonp method would be equal to the `dataType: "jsonp"` way.

With my code:

`app.fetch = function() {
    $http.jsonp("http://adventuretime.wikia.com/api/v1/Articles/List?expand=1&category=Episodes&limit=200&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
    .then(function(results){
     return results.data.items;
    });
   };`
It throws the error:

`Refused to execute script from '*&callback=JSON_CALLBACK' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Thanks again

Comment: @KlamHuggeren Then use You server. Just: `echo file_get_contents('http://adventuretime.wikia.com/api/v1/Articles/List?expand=1&category=Episodes&limit=200');` on PHP & `$http.get('link_to_You_fn').success(function(data){});` on JS;

Comment: you was right! I made the php file with the file_get_contents method and $http.get that file in the Angular controller.

`$http.get('get.php').success(function(results){
    app.episodes = results.items;
   });`

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understand CORS has to be enabled on the server

Correct.

> However I don't know if that's the case with Wikia.

Since you get the error message:

> > No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

… it is not enabled.

---

> So JSONP seems to be the only way.

JSONP is a hack to work around the same origin policy. It isn't as elegant as CORS (which is designed to give explicit permission) but it requires that the server express the data in JSONP.

The error message:

> > Refused to execute script from '*&callback=JSON_CALLBACK' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

means that the response to the HTTP request is not JSONP (which would have an `application/javascript` Content-Type), so the server doesn't support it.

---

A website can't instruct a web browser to make an HTTP request to another server and give the response to its JavaScript without explicit permission from the site the request is being made to.

You'll need to look at an alternative where the request to the server doesn't come from the browser. e.g. by proxying the request through your own server.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Quentin! :) So the only way is proxying the request. Can you link to some reading material on the subject? Creating a proxyserver for a simple JSON request seems a little overkill?