# AngularJS RESTAPI call throwing error

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS. I was trying to make a RESTapi call using standard `$http` service but I'm not getting a successful response. Any clue what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm calling the URL (URL is rendering fine when I ping it): http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json

The error i'm receiving is:

```
{"data":null,"status":0,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote","params":{"format":"json"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

My Angularjs test code is:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app2'),['app2']);
});

angular.module('app2',[])
  .controller('testNamesCtrl',function($scope,$http){

        $http({method:'GET',url:'http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote',params:{format:"json"}})
        .then(
                function(response){
                    $scope.record = response.data;
                $scope.record1 = response;
            }, function(response){
                $scope.record1 = response;
            });
  });
```

Comment: What HTTP status code are you getting? Check the browser console (the Network tab), there might be some clues already.

Comment: .jsonp might be the answer as suggested in the comments. Following was the error - XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://runnerp14.codenvycorp.com:49782' is therefore not allowed access.
testNamesCtrl.js:36 Object {data: null, status: 0, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, You try make cross domain request. You can try use [$http.jsonp(url)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) for this. But it was work only if server allows use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

And as I see, this server not allowed. In this case, you can prepare data on Your server.

```
echo file_get_contents(url);
```

[Example;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899651/angularjs-request-json-from-other-domain/31901873#31901873)

Comment: Thanks you very much!