# Get the value from json url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am developing a simple application with AngularJS and I want to get the value of the price dynamically I mean to get it from a json data. Is this possible !

This is my **data.json**:

```
{
    "prix": {
        "prix_diesel": "8.54",
        "prix_essence": "10.30",
        "prix_aditive": "0.00"
    }
}
```

And this is my **controller** :

```
angular.module("myApp",['zingchart-angularjs']).controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.cities =[{
    "name": "city A",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "c01",
          "name": "name1",
          "price": "15",//I want to get this price from the data.json. Get it from the value of prix_diesel attribute 
          "qte": "10" //I want to get this price from the data.json. Get it from the value of prix_essence attribute 
        }, {
          "id": "c02",
          "name": "name2",
          "price": "18",
          "qte": "11"
        }, {
          "id": "c03",
          "name": "name3",
          "price": "11",
          "qte": "14"
        }],
        "subsities": [{
          "name": "sub A1",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "sub01",
            "name": "nameSub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
          }, {
            "id": "sub02",
            "name": "nameSub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "13"
          }, {
            "id": "sub03",
            "name": "nameSub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "14"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "sub A2",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "ssub01",
            "name": "nameSsub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "7"
          }, {
            "id": "ssub02",
            "name": "nameSsub2",
            "price": "8",
            "qte": "1"
          }, {
            "id": "ssub03",
            "name": "nameSsub3",
            "price": "4",
            "qte": "19"
          }]
        }, {
          "name": "sub A3",
          "elements": [{
            "id": "sssub01",
            "name": "nameSssub1",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "11"
          }, {
            "id": "sssub02",
            "name": "nameSssub2",
            "price": "2",
            "qte": "15"
          }, {
            "id": "sssub03",
            "name": "nameSssub3",
            "price": "1",
            "qte": "15"
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "city B",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "cc01",
          "name": "name11",
          "price": "10",
          "qte": "11"
        }, {
          "id": "cc02",
          "name": "name22",
          "price": "14",
          "qte": "19"
        }, {
          "id": "cc03",
          "name": "name33",
          "price": "11",
          "qte": "18"
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "city C",
        "elements": [{
          "id": "ccc01",
          "name": "name111",
          "price": "19",
          "qte": "12"
        }, {
          "id": "ccc02",
          "name": "name222",
          "price": "18",
          "qte": "17"
        }, {
          "id": "ccc03",
          "name": "name333",
          "price": "10",
          "qte": "5"
        }]
      }]

  $scope.extractSubsities = function(itemSelected) {
    if(itemSelected && itemSelected.elements){
        $scope.data = itemSelected.elements;
    }

  }

 }]);
```

I set this up in my plunkr : [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NLO0xqyy7L7DHM4onOtQ?p=preview)

I search and I found that if I want to get the data from the URL, I'll need an XMLHttpRequest (with Angular, I can use $http.get). do you have any idea please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand Your question correctly, You need:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'data.json'})
.then(function(data) {
    if($scope.cities && $scope.cities[0] && $scope.cities[0].elements && $scope.cities[0].elements[0]){
        $scope.cities[0].elements[0].price = data.data.prix.prix_diesel;
        $scope.cities[0].elements[0].qte = data.data.prix.prix_essence;
    }
});
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hnlSsGrq2MSZSCdVoziY?p=preview)

Comment: `success` is deprecated...you shouldn't recommend using it

Comment: But the value of price of city A still 15 I want to get its value from data.json and from the value of prix_diesel exactly (8.54)

Comment: @charlietfl - Thank you, I didn't know it;

Comment: I want to get the value of price from the data.json I need to get the value automatically from dat.json. I mean to get 8.54 instead of 15

Comment: @Abderrahim my bad

Comment: @Abderrahim fixed... I hope;

Comment: @user3335966 you're genius I have just one question is when I use this url : http://total.smarteez.eu/submit/?station=101507 instead of data.json, it doesn't work 
Can you please see with me this issue

Comment: @Abderrahim `total.smarteez.eu` - it's Your server? If no - see something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32000289/3335966). If yes - try use `url: '/submit/?station=101507'`

Comment: @user3335966 no it's not my server I will check your other answer and I will back to you

Comment: @user3335966 can you please fix this in th plunker please

Comment: @Abderrahim No =) You never make it on plunker because crossdomain request are forbidden in browsers & as I understand  total.smarteez.eu does not support JSONP; Try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31901873/3335966) on Your server;

Comment: @user3335966 you mean to do something like :
$http.jsonp("http://total.smarteez.eu/submit/?station=101507")
  .then(function(data) {
   if($scope.cities && $scope.cities[0] && $scope.cities[0].elements && $scope.cities[0].elements[0]){
      $scope.cities[0].elements[0].price = data.data.prix.prix_diesel;
     $scope.cities[0].elements[0].qte = data.data.prix.prix_essence;
   }
 }, function(e){debugger;});

Comment: I will accept this answer because it fixed the first problem which is to load the data from data.json and I did a new a question for my second problem in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489029/how-can-i-get-the-value-from-json-url  thank you so much

Comment: @Abderrahim anyway PHP solution is the only way that I see for Your problem;

Answer (score 0):

Your markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cities">
Price: {{item.cities.price}}<br />
Quantity: {{item.cities.qte}}</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my question maybe I didn't explain it well anyway thanks for your answer