# How to Change Directive Dynamically in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm working with Angular 2+ and Material 2. I have some md-button(s) which I want to change to md-raised-button dynamically. For example I want this:

```
<a md-button [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
```

to change into this:

```
<a md-raised-button [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
```

when the link is active or I'm hovering over it etc.

Comment: why do you want to change md-button to md-raised-button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489761/angular-2-conditionally-add-attribute-directives) That is not supported.

but you can do this :

```
<a *ngIf="condition" md-button [routerLink]="['/home']" 
(mouseover)="condition= true" (mouseout)="condition= false">Home</a>

<a *ngIf="!condition" md-raised-button [routerLink]="['/home']"
(mouseover)="condition= true" (mouseout)="condition= false" >Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do this like this

```
<a [attr.md-button]="!value ? true : null"
[attr.md-raised-button]="value ? true : null"
(mouseover)="value = true"
(mouseout)="value = false"
[routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
```

By default the value will equal to false so md-button attribute will be added and on hover md-raised-button will be added and md-button will be removed you can extend logic regarding your need.

Answer (score 0):

The focus on a button is very simple as below

```
<button md-raised-button (click)="button1.focus()">Focus on Raised 
Button</button>
<button md-raised-button #button1>Raised button</button>
```

To change a `md-button` to `md-raised-button` you can use property binding as below

```
<a md-button routerLink="." [class.md-raised-button]="val">Flat button</a>

<button md-raised-button (click)="focus(button1)">Focus on Raised Button</button>

<button md-raised-button #button1>Raised button</button>
```

Typescript method will be as

```
    export class ButtonDemo {
       val:boolean=false;
       focus(element){
              element.focus();
              this.val=true;
        }
   }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/gk2NjJVSFCqaBtsX6Iap?p=preview)**