# How to conditionally add attribute to HTML element in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanted to change `mat-button` type dynamically based on certain conditions. This requires changing an attribute of `<button>` element dynamically. What is the best way to do that? 
Below is a stackblitz with basic setup.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-change-btn-type

I've seen this post. But there are total 8 button types and I think probably it won't be a good solution to add 8 conditions and bind them to a variable. Is there any better alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add conditional attribute in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2)

Comment: Not really. There are 8 button types available. And i don't think it would be a good solution to add 8 conditions for them. Instead I am seeking for an option to bind a variable to element itself in the form of attribute

Comment: This is not supported. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489761/angular-2-conditionally-add-attribute-directives

Comment: Thanks @MuhammetCanTONBUL. But is there any better approach/work-around to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by just changing the button element in your template to:

```
<button mat-button [ngClass]="selectedButtonType">This Button </button>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Oh, that's pretty useful. I didn't know that it works with classes as well. Thank you so much for help.